# Seamless SSO with CAS

Tags: java, spring, liferay, cas

I have Spring MVC app with Spring Security set up to use CAS. Also I have Liferay Portal 5.2.3 configured to use CAS.

1. I authenticate from app_1
2. Open Liferay Portal (app_2)
3. It does not check authentication immediately (I see sign in link)
4. If I click Sign in then CAS verifies that user is authenticated and I'm automatically signed in.

How to create link in app_1 that would suggest app_2 to validate authentication...

I have spring filter chain

```xml
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
```

And

```xml
<security:http entry-point-ref="casAuthenticationEntryPoint" auto-config="true" >
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/*/secure/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <security:custom-filter position="CAS_FILTER" ref="casAuthenticationFilter" />
    <security:anonymous enabled="false"/>
</security:http>
```

If I point all urls from app_1 to secure paths in app_2 then authentication is required (user is redirected to login page) so this doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by "suggest to validate authentication"

Comment: I mean suggest to check if authentication exists. If it does then user is loaded. If no authentication then request is processed as normal (unauthenticated) and user is not directed to cas login page.

Comment: It's the normal behavior. You don't have do to anything special to do that. Try to login on the cas and go to the login page. Are you still logged in ?

Comment: Yes. If I login in app_1 and go to login page in app_2 I'm still logged in. I want to achieve that after authenticating in app_1 I open a page in app_2, that doesn't require authentication, I would be authenticated. Currently I have to open a page that requires authentication or click log in (in app_2)

Comment: What is your filter configuration on app_2 ?